# Highresult doesn't show in fuzzy query Elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Hi I am trying to create "Did you mean" suggestion by using fuzzy in query using Elasticsearch. Example, when user search for word "applo" it will show "apple" instead (because there is product/brand name that contains word apple). So I want to highlight fuzzy matched word ("apple") and show it to user.

This is my properties:

```
 "properties": {
                "brand_name": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "store": true
                },
               {
                "product_name": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "store": true
                },
}
```

This is my query:

```
var should = { "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": ["product_name", "brand_name"],
            "query": "applo",
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "prefix_length": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*" + applo + "*",
            "fields": ["product_name", "brand_name"]
          }
        }
      ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    };

body = {
    size: 50,
    from: 0,
    query: {
      bool: should
    },
    aggs: buildAggregate(),
    "highlight": {
      "fields": {
        "brand_name": {},
        "product_name": {}
      }
    }
  };
```

The fuzzy and query works fine and give the correct result. However there is no highlight field in the result. What is missing in my query or is there anything to change in mapping properties?

Data Example:

```
 { took: 67,   timed_out: false,   _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5,
 skipped: 0, failed: 0 },   hits: { total: 2, max_score: null, hits: [
 [Object] ] },   aggregations:    { brands:
       { doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
         sum_other_doc_count: 0,
         buckets: [Array] },
      minimum: { value: 1000 },
      maximum: { value: 1000 },
      values:
       { doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
         sum_other_doc_count: 0,
         buckets: [Array] } } }
```

The object of hits:

> ```
> { _index: 'product',
>   _type: 'product',
>   _id: '1',
>   _score: null,
>   _source:
>    { 
>        product_name: 'Apple Watch',
>        brand_name: 'Apple'
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Data example will help to help you...

Comment: That is the data example (however i can't give the all the real data field because of privacy issue)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start:

1. Your mapping is not correct for searching fuzzy. You need to understand the difference between [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) data types. In short, keyword indexed as is and not able to change. Text converted to tokens and more conversions applied to tokens. For more understanding, how to indexing process I suggest to start reading [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-indexing-for-beginners-part1). Then I suggest changing your mapping:

```
"properties": {
   "brand_name": {
       "type": "text"
   },
   "product_name": {
      "type": "text"
    }
 }
```

2. After this change, you lost the ability to run aggregations on these fields. And here is thinking point. Because: if you make fielddata on then you lost performance and storage will be increased.
3. And for last point I suggest simplifying your query to query_string:

```
{
  "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "query": "applo~1"
     }
  }
}
```

Read about this querie [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).